# How to find out *why* a process is running on Ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

For example, I see postgres running . I can dig throught the logs but was hoping something like ptree might help.

Have tried systemctl but that does not tell me anything useful.

Comment: The why is pretty easy to answer: because someone or something started it. In case of Postgres, it's probably started automatically as a service during system boot.

Comment: Lol, yeah I know that but what service and why? That is what I mean. If it is just in the service autostart the answer is probably gone.